# Copying a key/value from one dictionary into another

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict with main data (roughly) as such: `{'UID': 'A12B4', 'name': 'John', 'email': 'hi@example.com}`

and I have another dict like: `{'UID': 'A12B4', 'other_thing: 'cats'}`

I'm unclear how to "join" the two dicts to then put "other_thing" to the main dict.  What I need is: `{'UID': 'A12B4', 'name': 'John', 'email': 'hi@example.com, 'other_thing': 'cats'}`

I'm pretty new to comprehensions like this, but my gut says there has to be a straight forward way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you want to use the `dict.update` method:

```
d1 = {'UID': 'A12B4', 'name': 'John', 'email': 'hi@example.com'}
d2 = {'UID': 'A12B4', 'other_thing': 'cats'}
d1.update(d2)
```

Outputs:

```
{'email': 'hi@example.com', 'other_thing': 'cats', 'UID': 'A12B4', 'name': 'John'}
```

From the [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

> Update the dictionary with the key/value pairs from other, overwriting existing keys. Return None.

Comment: Bang, cheers man that was what I just couldn't get.  The simplicity own.  Thanks.

Comment: @mhlester : what if i wanted to copy only the first two values from d1 to d2?

Comment: @ClintWhaley it sounds like you're asking a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Is this copy by value or copy by reference? I ask because I really need to cut and paste the row from one dictionary to another, then once that row is in the new dict I need to add a key/value to that row (which is obviously a dict).

Comment: @user3656612 it is by reference, as is typical for python objects

Answer (score 4):

If you want to join dictionaries, there's a great built-in function you can call, called `update`.

Specifically:

```
test = {'A': 1}
test.update({'B': 2})
test
>>> {'A':1, 'B':2}
```