# How to copy one key pair value from one dictionary to another in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Lets say I have a dictionary:

```
mydict = {"color":"green",
          "type":"veg",
          "fruit":"apple",
          "level": 5
          }
new_dict = {}
```

I would like to append the key "color" and "fruit" and their values receptively into the `new_dict`. what is the easiest way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copying a key/value from one dictionary into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719842/copying-a-key-value-from-one-dictionary-into-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easiest way is this:

```
new_dict["color"] = mydict["color"]
```

however, if you had a larger list of items you need to pass to a new dict, you could use the following:

```
items = ["color", "fruit"]
for item in items:
    new_dict[item] = mydict[item]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
new_dict = {x:mydict[x] for x in mydict if x in ('color','fruit')}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a set of what keys you want to add, then filter out the keys with a [dictionary comprehension](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/dict_comprehension.html):

```
>>> keys = {"color", "fruit"}
>>> new_dict = {k: v for k, v in mydict.items() if k in keys}
>>> new_dict
{'color': 'green', 'fruit': 'apple'}
```

If you only dealing with two keys, then `or` is another option as well:

```
>>> new_dict = {k: v for k, v in mydict.items() if k == "color" or k == "fruit"}
>>> new_dict
{'color': 'green', 'fruit': 'apple'}
```

Benefit of using a set here is in case you have many keys to filter. Using `or` could get ugly if you have more than 2 keys. Also dictionary keys are unique, so using a set makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work for your example.

```
mydict = {
    "color":"green",
    "type":"veg",
    "fruit":"apple",
    "level": 5
}
new_dict = {
    "color": mydict["color"],
    "fruit": mydict["fruit"]
}
```

If you need something more general:

```
def copy_dict(original, keys=None):
    keys = keys or {key for key in original}
    return {
        key: value for key, value in original if key in keys
    }

mydict = {
    "color":"green",
    "type":"veg",
    "fruit":"apple",
    "level": 5
}
new_dict = copy_dict(mydict, {'color', 'fruit'})
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
expected_keys=('color', 'fruit')
for k in expected_keys:
     new_dict[k]=mydict[k]
```