# Can you get the name of an object in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
weapons = {
    'sword' : {
        'damage' : 10,
        'type_damage' : 'sharp',
        'max_durability' : 20
    },
    'spear' : {
        'damage' : 7,
        'type_damage' : 'pointy',
        'max_durability' : 25
    },
    'log' : {
        'damage' : 5,
        'type_damage' : 'blunt',
        'max_durability' : 15
    }
}
inventory = {
    
}

inventory.update(weapons['sword'])
print(inventory)
```

I want to also add the 'sword' to inventory, not just the arguments, but I can't figure out how.

I want it to output

```
{'sword' : {'damage': 5, 'type_damage': 'blunt', 'max_durability': 15}}
```

but instead it gives

```
{'damage': 5, 'type_damage': 'blunt', 'max_durability': 15}
```

Comment: So you want `print({'sword': inventory})` or `inventory['sword'] = weapons['sword']`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy one key pair value from one dictionary to another in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401885/how-to-copy-one-key-pair-value-from-one-dictionary-to-another-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update` function returns only the value of a key-value pair.

To assign the key as well, you can do it like this:

```
weapons = {
    'sword' : {
        'damage' : 10,
        'type_damage' : 'sharp',
        'max_durability' : 20
    },
    'spear' : {
        'damage' : 7,
        'type_damage' : 'pointy',
        'max_durability' : 25
    },
    'log' : {
        'damage' : 5,
        'type_damage' : 'blunt',
        'max_durability' : 15
    }
}
inventory = {
    
}

inventory.update({'sword': weapons['sword']})
print(inventory)
```

Output:

```
{'sword': {'damage': 10, 'type_damage': 'sharp', 'max_durability': 20}}
```